# Why is '(x in list_1) == True' is True but 'x in list_1 == True' is False?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-expression, parentheses

I know this is can be a very basic question, but I found something curious on Python. I will try to explain this with the following example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
n1 = 1
```

We know the following:

```
print( n1 in l ) # True # is n1 in the list l1?
print( not(n1 in l) ) # False # is n1 not in the list l1?
```

instead of not I can use:

```
print( (n1 in l) == True ) # True 
# this will be like
# True == True
# True
```

My question is when I don't use the parentheses, ex:

```
print( n1 in l == True ) # False
```

Here the answer from the console is False

I was trying to understand the logic about this

So if I try to do it step by step

```
n1 in l == True
l == True # this is False, l es not a boolean True, it is a list
n1 in False # this is not False, actually if you run it it will be an error

print( n1 in False) # TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

Therefore, why if I run:

```
print( n1 in l == True )
```

The answer on the console is False?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
print( n1 in l == True ) # True
```

to be the same as:

```
print( (n1 in l) == True ) # True
```

Comment: This is actually a *chained comparison*, which is more normally used to do useful things like `0 <= x < 100`.  The equivalent of your `n1 in l == True` is `(n1 in l) and (l == True)` (except that `l` is only evaluated once).

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence): _Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have the same precedence and **have a left-to-right chaining feature as described in the Comparisons section**_. `n1 in l == True` is same as `(n1 in l) and (l == True)`

Comment: As a side note - you really should not make comparison to `True`, as also mentioned in PEP8

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `==` and `in` has the same precedence so recommended to use the parentheses.

Doesn't make any sense because in should only work for the types mentioned in the docs but this is the fun of dynamically typed languages :D

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence